# Dificuldade com layout do listview no xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Veja essa imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu layout está quebrado. Veja que o nome do cliente é: **Sebastiao Loureiro de Almeida** e na listview aparece **Sebastiao** e percebe-se que o restante do nome fica mais para baixo, aparecendo apenas a "ponta do iceberg" do nome. Minha dificuldade está em aumentar o tamanho da célula ou um scroll horizontal. Tentei fazer um scroll, colocando todo stacklayout dentro, mas não funcionou. Veja o xaml da mainpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Autorizador"
             x:Class="Autorizador.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,0,0">
            <Label Text="Adicionar um Produto" TextColor="Green" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Label x:Name="txtNome" Text="Cliente" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label x:Name="txtCategoria" Text="Vendedor" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label x:Name="txtPreco" Text="Juros" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                    HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <!--<Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Adicionar/Atualizar Produto" 
                    Clicked="btnAdicionar_Clicked" FontSize="Small"/>-->
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,5,10,0">
                <ListView x:Name="listaLibera" ItemSelected="listaLibera_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <!--<ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>-->
                                <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Cliente}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Vendedor}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Juros}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Filial}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

O C# da Mainpage

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        DataService dataService;
        List<Liberacao> libera;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataService = new DataService();
            AtualizaDados();
        }


        async void AtualizaDados()
        {
            libera = await dataService.GetLiberaAsync();
            listaLibera.ItemsSource = libera.OrderBy(item => item.Cliente).ToList();
        }

        private bool Valida()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNome.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCategoria.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPreco.Text))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void listaLibera_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var libera = e.SelectedItem as Liberacao;

            txtNome.Text = "Cliente: " + libera.Cliente;
            txtCategoria.Text = "Vendedor: " + libera.Vendedor;
            txtPreco.Text = "Juros: " + libera.Juros.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a propriedade `HasUnevenRows` à sua ListView e atribua o valor `true`a ela.

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="listaLibera" ItemSelected="listaLibera_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
```

Fonte:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows

Comment: Armindo, ok, apareceu, mas eu tenho a coluna Juros que o 2.5 ficou um em baixo do outro, ou seja, tem como aumentar horizontalmente as colunas? Se for o caso de outra pergunta eu posto outra.

Comment: Acrescente `WidthRequest="40"` à Label juros e veja se te atende. Altere o valor 40 conforme a sua necessidade. De qualquer forma, acredito que 4 colunas não seja o layout ideal.

Comment: Aumentei até 240 e percebi que parece que tem um limite, ou seja, ele não cria automaticamente uma rolagem, então, por mais que eu aumente, parece que atige a um máximo e por mais que eu altere o valor para mais, continua no mesmo tamanho.