# Exibir Lista de Objetos em uma ListView - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

A duvida é a seguinte, quero exibir uma lista de objetos na minha View usando uma ListView. Atualmente o código esta assim:

```
<ListView x:Name="listaDestinos" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaDestinos}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" WidthRequest="100"  HeightRequest="40">
                <Label Text="Paradas" TextColor="White" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="100">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Linha}" FontSize="15"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" FontSize="15"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Origem}" FontSize="15" ></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Destino}" FontSize="15"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Municipio}" FontSize="15"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Desse jeito que esta na tela aparece apenas o objeto relacionado ao "Linha" e "Nome", os outros três(Origem, Destino e Municipio) não aparecem. **Quero saber como faço para aparecer todos os cinco campos, ou seja, quero saber como aumentar o tamanho de espaço para visualização destes objetos**. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar. atenciosamente.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione na sua listview o `HasUnevenRows="True"`

```
<ListView x:Name="listaDestinos" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaDestinos}" HasUnevenRows="True">
```

De uma pesquisada antes que acha fácil [Uma pergunta igual a sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234886/dificuldade-com-layout-do-listview-no-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Agradeço sua resposta, e realmente eu deveria ter pesquisado antes.